# Does jQuery.html() method validates the HTML passed as parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, w3c

I have an Ajax request that returns an HTML code that I want to place in a certain place in my already generated HTML.

I tried to use the jQuery.html() method but It's not generating the HTML that I receive from the server. I used an console.log to inspect the HTML generated and it's correct, but still the HTML that is appended to the DOM does not match what I wrote.

I think the HTML generated is not W3C-compliant and jQuery validates it and if it's wrong, automatically tries to fix it.

I stopped using the jQuery.html(string) function and started using jQuery.append(string) and got the result I was hoping.

Before someone asks, I'm not responsible to write the HTML code, I just receive how it has to be written and do it.

**EDIT:** Providing more information:

The original HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>System</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link href="/includes/css/global/botoes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/includes/css/global/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/includes/css/global/menu_horizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/includes/css/global/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/includes/css/global/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-pt-BR.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/plugins/numeric-pack/jquery.numeric.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/plugins/validate/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/plugins/block-ui/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/plugins/masked-input/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/plugins/sigr/jquery.sigr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/jquery/plugins/form/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/menu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/global/sigr-util.js"></script>
        <meta name="titulo" content="SIGR - Sistema Integrado Gestor de Relat&oacute;rios" />
        <meta name="subtitulo" content="Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Domiciliar" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var codigoUsuario = '';
            var codigoPerfilAcesso = '';
            var urlRelatorio = 'gerarRelatorioInternacaoDomiciliarAjax.do';
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="internacaoDomiciliar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#CC092F"><img src="logomarca.jpg"></td>
                <td align="right" bgcolor="#CC092F"><img src="trama1.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#A80000">&nbsp;</td>
                <td align="right" bgcolor="#A80000">
                <div class="infoFuncionarioMenu">v1.0.0</div>
                <img src="tronco.jpg">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td align="left" colspan="2"></td></tr>
        </table>
        <table id="tabela_principal">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="sigr.png" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="subtitulo">Subtitle</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="celulaMensagens">
                    <div id="msgErros" class="mensagens_erro fadeOutAndEmpty"></div>
                    <div id="msgSucesso" class="mensagens_sucesso fadeOutAndEmpty"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table id="tabela_principal">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <form id="form" name="internacaoDomiciliarForm" action="internacaoDomiciliar.do" method="post">
                                    <table width="95%" id="tabela_interna">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr valign="middle">
                                                <th colspan="6">Report</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr valign="middle" class="infos">
                                                <td width="8%" align="left" class="td_label">Data Inicial</td>
                                                <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                                                    <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicial" size="12" maxlength="10" value="" id="dataInicial" class="data"/>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="8%" align="left" class="td_label">Data Final</td>
                                                <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                                                    <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinal" size="12" maxlength="10" value="" id="dataFinal" class="data"/>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="9%" align="left" class="td_label">Refer&ecirc;ncia</td>
                                                <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                                                    <select name="filtro.referencia" id="referencia" class="numerico">
                                                        <option value="">-- Selecione --</option>
                                                        <option value="1">Data Fim Internação Prorrogação</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Data Recebimento Relatório</option>
                                                        <option value="3">Data Resposta Internação Domiciliar</option>
                                                        <option value="4">Data Resposta Visita</option>
                                                        <option value="5">Data Solicitação</option>
                                                        <option value="6">Data Avaliação Solicitação Internação Domiciliar</option>
                                                        <option value="7">Data Solicitação Visita</option>
                                                        <option value="8">Data Última Visita</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                               <td width="8%" align="left" class="td_label">Cart&atilde;o</td>
                                               <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                                                  <input type="text" name="filtro.cartao" size="25" maxlength="15" value="" id="cartao" class="numerico"/>
                                               </td>
                                               <td width="8%" align="left" class="td_label">Nome Segurado</td>
                                               <td width="59%" colspan="3" align="left" class="td_dados" id="txtNomeDoSegurado"></td>
                                           </tr>
                                           <tr>
                                               <td width="8%" align="left" class="td_label">Estipulante</td>
                                               <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                                                  <input type="text" name="filtro.estipulante" size="25" maxlength="15" value="" id="estipulante" class="numerico"/>
                                               </td>
                                               <td width="8%" align="left" class="td_label">Nome Estipulante</td>
                                               <td width="59%" colspan="3" align="left" class="td_dados" id="txtNomeEstipulante"></td>
                                           </tr>
                                           <tr>
                                               <td width="8%" align="left" class="td_label">Referenciado</td>
                                               <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                                                  <input type="text" name="filtro.referenciado" size="25" maxlength="15" value="" id="referenciado" class="numerico"/>
                                               </td>
                                               <td width="8%" align="left" class="td_label">Nome Referenciado</td>
                                               <td width="59%" colspan="3" align="left" class="td_dados" id="txtNomeReferenciado"></td>
                                           </tr>
                                           <tr>
                                               <td width="8%" align="left" class="td_label">Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o</td>
                                               <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                                                   <input type="text" name="filtro.solicitacao" size="25" maxlength="15" value="" id="solicitacao" class="numerico"/>
                                               </td>
                                               <td width="8%" align="left" class="td_label">Senha</td>
                                               <td width="59%" colspan="3" align="left" class="td_dados">
                                                   <input type="text" name="filtro.senha" size="25" maxlength="15" value="" id="senha"/>
                                               </td>
                                           </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                   </table>
                                   <br />
                                   <table width="95%" id="tabela_botoes">
                                       <tr>
                                           <td width="100%" align="center">
                                               <button class="margem_botoes">Consultar</button>
                                               <button class="margem_botoes" type="reset">Limpar</button>
                                               <a href="/"><button class="margem_botoes navegavel" type="button">Voltar</button></a>
                                           </td>
                                       </tr>
                                   </table>
                               </form>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr id="respostaRelatorio" style="width: 100%; display: block; overflow: auto;"></tr>
                   </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="carregando" style="display: none;">
            <p style="font-weight: bolder; color: white;">Carregando...</p>
            <img src="bradesco.gif" width="70" height="65" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The HTML that is generated after the Ajax being submitted:

```
    <table class="tabela_interna" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="titulo">
            <th>Dias</th>
            <th>Observa&ccedil;&atilde;o</th>
            <th>Cidade</th>
            <th>Cart&atilde;o</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Data Nascimento</th>
            <th>Patologia</th>
            <th>Sexo</th>
            <th>Solct c/ Liminar Judicial</th>
            <th>UF Int Dom</th>
            <th>Cod Prest Visit Dom</th>
            <th>Nome Prest Visit Dom</th>
            <th>Cod Prest Int Dom</th>
            <th>Nome Prest Int Dom</th>
            <th>Tempo Int</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Ramo</th>
            <th>Solct Autorizada Dir</th>
            <th>Cod Estipulante</th>
            <th>Nome Estipulante</th>
            <th>Rec&eacute;m-nato</th>
            <th>Data Receb Rel</th>
            <th>Data Fim Prorrog</th>
            <th>Data Solct</th>
            <th>Data Solct Visit</th>
            <th>Data Resp Visit</th>
            <th>Data Solct Aval Prest ID</th>
            <th>Data Resp Aval Prest ID</th>
            <th>Data Anals Visit Med</th>
            <th>Data Anals Aval Prest ID</th>
            <th>Aut Estipulante</th>
            <th>Cod Procedimento</th>
            <th>Nro Solct</th>
            <th>Program Atend Dom</th>
            <th>Senha Aut</th>
            <th>Local Int Hosp</th>
            <th>Client Concierge</th>
            <th>Senha Dom Ant</th>
            <th>Taxa Liminar</th>
            <th>SNE</th>
            <th>TQT</th>
            <th>Dep&ecirc;nd O2</th>
            <th>VM/BIPAP</th>
            <th>&Uacute;cera de Dec&uacute;bito</th>
            <th>GTT</th>
            <th>Fisio</th>
            <th>ATB Alto Custo</th>
            <th>Curativo</th>
            <th>Dieta Industr.</th>
            <th>Fono</th>
            <th>Indica&ccedil;&atilde;o Cl&iacute;nica</th>
            <th>Obs Int Dom</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>

            <tr align="left" class="off">
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Teste</td>
            <td>RJ</td>
            <td>13246467978</td>
            <td>Guilherme</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>Infecciosa</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>MG</td>
            <td>2011</td>
            <td>Guilherme</td>
            <td>431596</td>
            <td>Philippe</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>liberada</td>
            <td>870</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>dudu</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>13246467978</td>
            <td>546</td>
            <td>24 horas</td>
            <td>2f584</td>
            <td>america</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>5ffdf</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>DN: ; DC: ; DA: 24/06/2013; DAT: ; I: ; P: ; GR: </td>
            <td>teste</td>
            </tr>

        <tr align="left" class="">
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Teste</td>
            <td>RJ</td>
            <td>13246467978</td>
            <td>Guilherme</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>Infecciosa</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>MG</td>
            <td>2011</td>
            <td>Guilherme</td>
            <td>431596</td>
            <td>Philippe</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>liberada</td>
            <td>870</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>dudu</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>13246467978</td>
            <td>546</td>
            <td>24 horas</td>
            <td>2f584</td>
            <td>america</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>5ffdf</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>DN: ; DC: ; DA: 24/06/2013; DAT: ; I: ; P: ; GR: </td>
            <td>teste</td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="left" class="off">
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Teste</td>
            <td>RJ</td>
            <td>13246467978</td>
            <td>Guilherme</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>Infecciosa</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>MG</td>
            <td>2011</td>
            <td>Guilherme</td>
            <td>431596</td>
            <td>Philippe</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>liberada</td>
            <td>870</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>dudu</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>13246467978</td>
            <td>546</td>
            <td>24 horas</td>
            <td>2f584</td>
            <td>america</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>5ffdf</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>DN: ; DC: ; DA: 24/06/2013; DAT: ; I: ; P: ; GR: </td>
            <td>teste</td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="left" class="">
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Teste</td>
            <td>RJ</td>
            <td>13246467978</td>
            <td>Guilherme</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>Infecciosa</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>MG</td>
            <td>2011</td>
            <td>Guilherme</td>
            <td>431596</td>
            <td>Philippe</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>liberada</td>
            <td>870</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>dudu</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>13246467978</td>
            <td>546</td>
            <td>24 horas</td>
            <td>2f584</td>
            <td>america</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>5ffdf</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>DN: ; DC: ; DA: 24/06/2013; DAT: ; I: ; P: ; GR: </td>
            <td>teste</td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="left" class="off">
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Teste</td>
            <td>RJ</td>
            <td>13246467978</td>
            <td>Guilherme</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>Infecciosa</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>MG</td>
            <td>2011</td>
            <td>Guilherme</td>
            <td>431596</td>
            <td>Philippe</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>liberada</td>
            <td>870</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>dudu</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>29/11/13</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>13246467978</td>
            <td>546</td>
            <td>24 horas</td>
            <td>2f584</td>
            <td>america</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>5ffdf</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>DN: ; DC: ; DA: 24/06/2013; DAT: ; I: ; P: ; GR: </td>
            <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The function that does the Ajax request:

```
function carregaConteudoViaAjax(idElemento, url, dados) {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        dataType : "html",
        data: dados,
        type: "POST",
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        success : function(result, statusRequestAjax, xhr) {
            console.log(result);
            $(idElemento).append(result);
        },
        error : function(xhr, statusRequestAjax, error) {
            $("#msgErros").html(error);
        },
        complete : function() {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you check your selector? Post your relevant code here

Comment: Object.append should be identical to object.html if object is empty to start with

Comment: Try `$.parseHTML` and post the code in question

Comment: @mplungjan not if textNodes are in the html

Comment: you can copy the string from response body, and run it through [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) for confirmation

Comment: I'm formatting the HTML code, the original one and the returned after the Ajax submit.

Comment: W3C would validate the HTML because it's just a table that is returned. But the layout is not tableless here, so it's a table inside another table.

Comment: @megawac what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery's `.html()` function is just a wrapper around the browser's native `Element.innerHTML` property.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/cc19a6bd3b6183887b52a965e77234f4dd9684ca/src/manipulation.js#L407) The *browser* is what handles malformed HTML input, just like on JavaScriptless pages.

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content) are also semantically different. The former **replaces** content; the latter **appends** content.

Comment: Good answer, so the innerHTML can validate the HTML that is trying to be inserted?

Comment: Pretty much, though it's not just `innerHTML`. Browsers historically have been able to accept and render HTML which is technically not valid. This is an example of the [robustness principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)

Comment: But in this case I thing browsers are not rendering invalid HTML. You can see my edit and you'll the structure of the original HTML and the one that comes after the ajax submission.

Comment: BTW, I know that jQuery.html(string) replaces and jQuery.append(string) appends but the result shoub be identical in this case since the element that will receive the response is empty.